# Can I recover deleted files of my Linux HDD from Windows?

Tags: data-recovery

Can I recover deleted files of my Linux HDD from Windows?

I very recently removed a few files with `rm filename` and I want them back.

I have another HDD with Windows, can I recover the files from here? How?

And if not from Windows, how would you do it from an external Linux (e.g. USB)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` and `dd` for this. From another disk, run

```
# grep -a -b "text in the deleted file" /dev/sdXY
530159385076:some text in the deleted file
# dd if=/dev/sdXY count=8 skip=$(expr 530159385076 / 512 - 4)
```

where `-a` looks at the disk itself and `-b` prints the byte offset. `count=8` takes 8 blocks  and `skip` in this case goes back 4 blocks -- adjust to your needs.